# Retrofit returning null in android (API working and can get result in Advanced rest client )

Tags: android, retrofit

I just try to get user details with help of retrofit library, It Returns null, but in advance rest client with the same input, it is working properly.

**My ApiClient**

```
Public class Apiclient{
  public static final String BASE_URL = Webconstants.COMMON_URL;
  private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

  public static Retrofit getclient() {
    if (retrofit== null){
       retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                 .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                 .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                 .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
  }
}
```

**My ApiInterface**

```
@Headers({"Content-Type: application/json"})
@POST("user/GetUserDetails")
Call<LoginResponce> Login(@Body JSONObject data);
```

And call be like

```
private void loginTask(JSONObject input){
    ApiInterfaces apiService = Apiclient.getClient().create(ApiInterfaces.class);
    Call<LoginResponce> login_call=apiService.Login(input);
    login_call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponce>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponce(Call<LoginResponce> call, Responce<LoginResponce> responce) {
           Error error = responce.body().getError;
           if(error.getError_data() == 0){
              User user = responce.body.getUser();
           }else{
           }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponce> call, Throwable t){
        }
     });
   }
}
```

LoginResponce model

```
public class LoginResponce {

    @SerializedName("error")
    private Error error;

    @SerializedName("users")
    private User user;

    public Error getError(){ return error;}
    public User getUser(){ return user;}
}
```

Error and User are Models of the same kind. In Advanced rest client, it's `Content-Type` is `application/json`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not pass **JsonObject**. Instead pass model object you will get a result.

Your model object converted into json and transmitted. So you can't directly pass **JsonObject** there.

for example, if you are sending username and password to the API. you have to send like this.

Your Model:

```
public UserModel{
    private String userName;
    private String password;

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
}
```

You have to set data and call api like this.

```
UserModel model = new UserModel();
model.setUserName("username");
model.setPassword("password");

@Headers({"Content-Type: application/json"})
@POST("user/GetUserDetails")
Call<LoginResponce> Login(@Body UserModel data);
```

Hope it helps:)